# Jasmine failed to instantiate module due to unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I currently get the following error when trying to run Jasmine tests.

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module X due to:
> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ANGULAR_DEBUG

Has anybody encountered this before?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your karma config, a sample test so its easier to look at?

Comment: Is ANGULAR_DEBUG something you wrote?  Errors like this mean that angular cannot resolve something that is being requested from the IOC container.  Typically, it means that when you defined your application you forgot to include a module.

Comment: Hi dwbartz, you did help slightly. I removed the reference to ANUGLAR_DEBUG, I now get the following " Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- homeCtrl"

Comment: @SwimmingG I'm glad you were able to fix the issue. Please post your solution as an answer for others.